# Cannot get sound to work in Skype

Tags: sound

I'm battling with Ubuntu 11.10 for a few days now, I got most issues resolved, like getting rid of the Unity and installing Kde.

But there is a problem with audio.

My PC has an X-Fi audio card that's connected to digital receiver by an optical cable, which always worked. Windows was sending DTS 5.1 encoded sound via the optical cable, and all 6 channels worked as expected.

I managed to get the sound working in Ubuntu too, by selecting "Master Channel - IEC958", which plays stereo sound through digital 5.1 receiver, and it works in most applications - Firefox+Flash, VLC, Shell sounds. But the Skype is totally silent.

By default it's left at "default device", but it doesn't seem to work on any of the 30 devices that are offered through Skype options screen either.

I'm completely lost, and I have no more ideas where to look and how to troubleshoot the problem...

Can anyone give me an advice on where to look next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Bummer, let's hope the bug is not present in 12.04. My solution was to remove Skype for now.